# How to read Data from App web and write data to a host web by making REST calls

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest, csom

my Question :**How to read/copy Data(images folder) from App web and write/Upload data to a host web (Picture Library) by making REST calls with the cross-domain library.**

i have Created SharePoint hosted app ,also created Picture library using CSOM on Host Web url, 
**Now** in my APP have **image folder**  with some images, trying to read that images(from APP Web) and upload that images to Picture Library on Host web using rest call,

so is that Possible to use combination of CSOM and rest calls?
how to achieve this task in SharePoint Online (office 365)?

Answer (score 0):

The following resources have the information you need to do what you want to do:

[Lists and list items REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn531433.aspx)

[Files and folders REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx)

[Uploading Files in SharePoint 2013 using CSOM and REST](http://www.shillier.com/archive/2013/03/26/uploading-files-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom-and-rest.aspx)

Comment: i'm working on it...